# How would you call this element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to make a slider like this but I'm not sure where to start or how to start looking for information as I don't even know how to call it.

Is there a specific name for this? I came across Marquee but I think that is a different thing, it's basically a slider that goes infinitely, but instead of you moving the slider, the whole tape moves and the selector is the center.

[image: Slider]

Comment: I think we neeed more information. Yes a continuous sliding banner like that is sometimes called  marquee but don't use the now deprecated HTML tag marquee, instead use CSS to continuously scroll. You don't say how long the 'tape' is or what happens when it comes to the end. Also the extra bit seems to be how the user selects the 'current' value, please describe that some more, have a go at coding and if still stuck put your code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think this way. Make slider with [scroll-snap mandatory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type). Start with div, which is two times wider than the viewport. (y-axis overflow). Inside that div, put segments of your slider with values. (map array of values).

[Your slider segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/887Jp.png)

On when the right side of the container riches viewport, you can do the math and calculate new values for the array you are mapping